# How to record the time execution of a script in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

I am developing a timetable system using Yii.
All working fine, but how can I get the time execution for a script or action.

For example, I have the action "scheduleOptimize".
And I want to know how long does it take to run the action in PHP.

Somebody help me please.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can do with `Logging` option in yii

Refer this link.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging

you can do:

1. Message Logging
2. Message Routing
3. Message Filtering
4. Logging Context Information
5. Performance Profiling
6. Profiling SQL Executions

Answer (score 9):

Simple snippet, returns execution time in seconds, 5 symbols after comma precision.

```
   <?php echo sprintf('%0.5f',Yii::getLogger()->getExecutionTime())?>
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need Yii to do it for you. Use native PHP.

```
$start_time = microtime(true); 

//Do you stuff here
do_stuff('here');

$end_time = microtime(true);

//dividing with 60 will give the execution time in minutes other wise seconds
$execution_time = ($end_time - $start_time)/60;
```

Comment: Why the downvote (without an explanation). This works 100%, and is recommended rather than adding another multi-levelled called to a library that will provide skewed results. If you bothered to check. Yii uses microtime() in the CLogger{} class.

Comment: this is a good answer.... dunno who down voted it ... I use this myself... great answer man.

Comment: Now for performance measurements, using [hrtime()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.hrtime.php) is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants to know the execution time since Yii2 starts, I suggest the following:

`\Yii::getLogger()->getElapsedTime();`

You can use it how many times you like. It uses as "begin time" a constant defined on the very beginnig of the framework and subtract it from current_timestamp()